# Randomizing a 2D array using 2 characters?

Tags: c

Hi there Stack Overflow community. I'd like to know how to randomly generate a 2D array using only 2 characters in C, under the condition that the top row, bottom row, first column, and last column are the same character with exception to 2 elements only. I don't need a walkthrough, I just need a clearer idea on how to accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated.

An example:

```
@#@@@@   
@#@@@@   
@##@@@  
@@#@@@
```

Comment: Cool, what have you done so far Melody?

Comment: Use a modulo of 2 `%2` to get a 0 or a 1, done on a random number.

Comment: This is a very simple task, if you can't do it, then you have more problems than you think, if you tried something and got stuck, this comunity will be glad to help you for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Generate the center first like this:

```
for(i = 1; i < (row - 1); i++) {
  for(j = 1; j < (column - 1); j++) {
      // select random caracteres to this positions
  }
}
```

Now has left an 'array' at borders to make the random.

Your array lenght is: 2n + 2m - 4 (n = rows, m = collumns, - 4 common indexes)

Now generate two random positions and gerenate a single random character.

That two positions must be this character and the others you use the other character.

Example:

```
[][][][]
[][][][]
[][][][]
```

Completing the center:

```
[][][][]
[][@][#][]
[][][][]
```

Lenght array: (2*3 + 2*4) - 4 = 10

Random positions = 3 and 9

You can use a clock time to make the indexes:

```
[0][1][2][3]
[9][@][#][4]
[8][7][6][5]
```

Random character for the postions = "#"

```
[][][][#]
[#][@][#][]
[][][][]
```

Complete with the order character.

```
[@][@][@][#]
[#][@][#][@]
[@][@][@][@]
```

Of course, you will need to implement the clock walk in the matrix.

Hope this help =)